# How to set jquery tooltip for certain element or class

Tags: jquery, html

How can i set a tooltip for certain html element if I either know the class or id.

I have tried this so far but no luck.

```
$("[id*=lblAvgKPI]").tooltip();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting tooltip text to a div element dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571791/setting-tooltip-text-to-a-div-element-dynamically)

Comment: Not really a duplicate of the cited that I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test for both id `myId` or class `myClass` you can add them both to your selector separated by a `,`.

```
$("#myId, .myClass").tooltip();
```

Comment: or $("#myId, .myClass")